David thinks if he can/could grow taller, he will/would attract more attention from others. - what is the difference?
Example 1

John: My friend David thinks [if he can grow taller, he will attract more attention from others.] However, I don't think he can grow taller anymore because he is a grown adult.

Does this example work? Despite the fact that the speaker John doesn't think David can grow taller, the present tense is still correct usage here because David thinks he can, right?
Example 2

John: My friend David thinks [if he could grow taller, he would attract more attention from others.] However, I don't think he can grow taller anymore because he is a grown adult.

Does this example work? Does subjunctive mood in bold reflect John's or David's estimate of impossibility of David growing taller?

I don't think it's subjunctive. Could is just the past tense of can, which puts it further away from "real, now". Since people can't voluntarily grow taller, My friend David thinks if he can grow taller... just sounds weird. Whereas ...if he could... acknowledges that he can't (it's an irrealis mood, known not to be possible).

...it would be different with ...thinks if he can earn more money..., because it's reasonable to suppose he can do that if he puts his mind to it.

Does this answer your question? Being taller can/could make him more attractive - Which is appropriate?

You're asking the difference between 'can' and 'could'. Have you done any research? In the body of your question you just seem to be asking "does this example work?" which isn't a question about English

That would be an example of a typical context that wants could only, which is a periphrastic form of irrealis, a kind of wishing. Now, if he actually believes it's possible. it would be "wishful thinking", which is a quasi-clinical phrase.

Both "work". "My friend David thinks if he can grow taller ..." implies that David thinks he can grow taller, which may be true. It would be weird though, as FumbleFingers says.

Does this answer your question? How to use "average" as a verb?

@FumbleFingers Thank you. So, if David thinks he can and John doesn't think David can and when John reports it like in the examples, are both "can" and "could" acceptable? Because "can" and "could" in the examples are just reflections of David's perception and John's respectively?

Your context here is inherently unnatural, so it's hard to say what "makes sense". John might say "My friend David thinks he can grow taller as a way to attract more women", just as he might say "My friend David thinks he is Napoleon". In both cases John is just reporting what David thinks, no matter how daft John thinks David's ideas are. But when it's ...thinks if he could grow taller... or ...thinks if he was / were to be Napoleon, the "source" of the dubious postulate / condition becomes more vague. If John used "can / is" there it could imply he believes it too.


Can/Will are used for situations that are more certain or definite.

eg "I can swim", "I will go swimming today".

Could/Would are used for situations that are more hypothetical, polite, or less certain.

eg "I could swim if I took lessons", "I would go swimming if I had time".
So, using can/will in your examples suggests that David believes he is able to grow taller, and that he will get more attention when (not if) he does.
Switching that to could/would makes it hypothetical - David believes that, if there was some way to be taller then, in that hypothetical situation, he would get more attention.
Neither makes much logical sense. It would make more sense to use was/would. 'Was' can also indicate hypothetical conditions in the present. In other words, instead of imagining a hypothetical way that he could grow taller, he's just imagining what it would be like if he was taller. Essentially he is making the observation that taller people get more attention.

David believes that, if he was taller, he would get more attention.


Ok. I get it that David's perception of the likelyhood affects whether he chooses to use subjunctive or not to reflect that, but the whole thing is reported by John, so if John doesn't think it is impossible for David to grow taller but David does believe he will, what happens then? Does John's opinion has a say in determining whether to use subjunctive in the clause? For example, Mary thinks she will finish the program and work at Google, and I say to one friend of mine, "Mary thinks she would get a chance to work at Google if she finished the program. That is impossible because she is lazy."

@vincentlin John is saying what "David thinks". That's different from stating what somebody else says. If I wanted to express the idea that someone else has completely wrong thinking on a matter, I'd be more likely to quote them verbatim - ie "David said...". Otherwise yes, what John says about probability would probably be assumed to be his own thoughts.

As far as I can think, I can't see a situation in which the choice of tenses has anything to say about John's opinion. This is reported speech, and the choices of "grows," "can grow," "could grow" etc. depend only on David's outlook. John's opinion is communicated by the second sentence or by his tone. Heck, we could even have this:

Pfft—David. He thinks he can grow taller.

This isn't even a conditional or hypothetical, just a simple declarative sentence! But the wording makes John's scorn and disagreement clear.
So to your examples, John could choose either version viably, and the difference would depend on what David thinks.
